# Is this a rule of matrix algebra? (Eigenvectors)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

In my lecture notes, there is this explanation of how to find eigenvalues. There is a step that I don't understand, highlighted in yellow.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKQMF.png)

Is this a rule of matrix algebra? To me it looks like the notation indicates that you can take the last element (a33) of a 3x3 matrix and put it outside the matrix if a13 = a23 = a31 = a32 = 0. Ie.

\begin{bmatrix}a11&a12&a0\\a21&a22&a0\\0&0&a33\end{bmatrix}
Is equal to \begin{bmatrix}a11&a12\\a21&a22\end{bmatrix} Times a33 (Sorry, didn't get the a33 to align nicely with the matrix).

If it is a rule, I would appreciate knowing what it is called so I can read about it. If it is not a rule, I would appreciate an explanation of what is being done in this procedure.

Comment: This is called "Laplace expansion" in calculating determinant. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I now understand that I had interpreted the Laplace expansion in a too restrictive way so that I applied it wrongly in my earlier attempt. So I now learnt how to use it (and also what it was called).

Comment: Note that it's not true about matrices, but only about determinants!